# Ajuda - Python3: Transformar dados de um CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Eu tenho um ficheiro csv com o seguinte formato:

| id | text | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I am happy | happy |
| 1 | I am happy | fun |
| 1 | I am happy | energy |
| 2 | cool | happy |
| 2 | cool | satisfaction |
| 3 | this is amazing! | happy |

E quero converter num novo ficheiro CSV, em que os valores que aparecem na coluna de "label" passam a ser novas colunas, e nessas novas colunas aparece o valor "1" se a label estiver associada ao "id" e ao "texto". Caso contrário, fica com o valor de "0".

Para o exemplo dado anteriormente, deve escrever num novo ficheiro CSV o seguinte resultado:

| id | text | happy | fun | energy | satisfaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I am happy | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | cool | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | this is amazing! | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Mostre algo que você tenha tentado fazer, isso incentiva as pessoas a te ajudarem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja a documentação do [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

Ele faz exatamente o que você quer.

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "text": ["I am happy", "I am happy", "I am happy", "cool", "cool", "this is amazing"], "label": ["happy", "fun", "energy", "happy", "satisfaction", "happy"]})

print(df)

   id             text         label
0   1       I am happy         happy
1   1       I am happy           fun
2   1       I am happy        energy
3   2             cool         happy
4   2             cool  satisfaction
5   3  this is amazing         happy
```

### Gerando resultado

```
resultado_df = pd.crosstab(df.text, df.label)

print(resultado_df)

label            energy  fun  happy  satisfaction
text
I am happy            1    1      1             0
cool                  0    0      1             1
this is amazing       0    0      1             0
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor fazer um comentário com o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta.